# Check if array is sorted using recursion

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I am getting true as answer even for unsorted(isNonDescending) arrays. Where is the bug?
I want to break the array into smaller problem from the start of the array only.

//Check for isNonDescending.

```
public class AlgoAndDsClass {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        int[] unsortedArry = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        int[] unsortedArry2 = { 1, 2, 4, 3 };
        System.out.println(isSorted(unsortedArry, unsortedArry.length));
       System.out.println(isSorted(unsortedArry2, unsortedArry2.length));


    }

    private static boolean isSorted(int[] arr, int size) {
        if (size == 0 || size == 1)
            return true;

        if (arr[0] > arr[1]) {
            return false;
        }
        System.out.println(arr.length);
        boolean smallwork = isSorted(arr, size - 1);

        return smallwork;

    }
```

Comment: The bug is here: `isSorted(arr, size - 1)`

Comment: @akuzminykhYes i know.but what to write their

Comment: (`isNonDescending()` was a more precise name.)

Comment: (This is not chat: Edit your question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing the size of the array as a parameter, which makes no sense anyway, because you can simply call `arr.length`, you should pass a starting index and increase it with each recursive call until you have reached the length of your array.

```
private static boolean isSorted(int[] arr, int index) {
    if(arr.length == 0 || arr.length == 1 || index == arr.length - 1){
        return true;
    }
    if (arr[index] > arr[index + 1]) {
        return false;
    }
    return isSorted(arr, index + 1);
}
```

and call from main with `0` as a starting index

```
System.out.println(isSorted(unsortedArry,0));
System.out.println(isSorted(unsortedArry2,0));
```

Answer (score 1):

you keep on checking the same 2 elements, try using the size variable instead as the arrray indexes.
For exmaple, if the first 2 elements are sorted you'll get true, thats because you check only the first two elements in the arrray.

Comment: @rf_student.Right.how to move those indices

Comment: instead checking using  if (arr[0] > arr[1]) {
            return false;
        }
check using if(arr[size-1]>arr[size]).
also your break condition should be:if(size == 0)

Comment: `your break condition should be:if(size == 0)` What would be the advantage?

Comment: @rf_student. I know i can start comparing from end of array.But in C we can solve this problem by comparing first 2 elemsts of arry from start. eg. `isSorted(arr+1, size - 1)`

Comment: @greybeard My solution works corretcly for C since we can use 
`isSorted(arr+1, size - 1) `.I am trying to do same in Java.

Comment: (@PaleDot So you found out Java is not C. Don't try to work against a tool's features. Your approach would work with [java.util.List<>](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#subList(int,int)).)

Answer (score 0):

Array is sorted if the sub-array from the start and up to one element before last is sorted and the last element is larger or equal to the element before last one.